# Delete elements from list of Tuples

Tags: haskell

Assuming I have the list of tuples:

```
[('X', 3.0), ('B', 0.0), ('N', 4.33)]
```

I would like a function that deletes all tuples from the list where the second element is 0 or below. My attempt:

```
dELS :: [(Char, Float)] ->  [(Char, Float)]
dELS x = [c | c <- x, snd x > 0.0]
```

But that returns...

```
*** Expression     : snd x
*** Term           : x
*** Type           : [(Char,Float)]
*** Does not match : (a,b)
```

Thoughts?

Comment: change to `snd c > 0 `

Comment: What compiler are you using? That does not look like GHC output...

Comment: @alternative: Three asterisks indicates Hugs. Poor DarioP ;-)

Answer (score 5):

When you do `c <- x`, you're using `c` as the name of an individual element of the list `x`, and it's `c` that you should be running `snd x > 0.0` on instead of `x`.  So change that last `x` to `c`.